# al usar el metodo mail() de php mailer,si envia el correo, pero ¿porque el estatus de la peticion http es "canceled"?

Tags: php, http

Estoy usando la librería php mailer para envió de correos, en mi proyecto esta funcionando bien, envía los correos que le indico, pero mi pregunta es ¿porque el status de la petición es "canceled"? ademas de eso al ver el detalle de la petición me dice esto "Provisional headers are shown". Por lo que me parece curioso que aunque el proceso se haga bien, el status de la petición sea "Canceled".

Comment: Sería bueno que nos dejaras ver el código que haz utilizado para enviar el correo (No la librería) y así poder darnos una idea de que error puedes tener.

Comment: creo que eso es cuando tienes el adblock plus [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger)